# Use attribute from derived class while using method from the base class?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I have the following code:

```
    #include <map>

class vehicle {
    private:
        int id = 0;
        std::map<std::pair<int, char>, int> seats{};
    public:
        void displaySeats();
    };
        
    class Bus : public vehicle {
    private:
        std::string type = "Bus";
    public:
        std::map<std::pair<int, char>, int> seats{ {{1,'A'},0 }, {{1,'B'},0 }, {{ 1,'C' }, 0}, {{ 1,'D' }, 0 }, {{ 1,'E' }, 0 },
            {{2,'A'},0 }, {{2,'B'},0 }, {{ 2,'C' }, 0}, {{ 2,'D' }, 0 }, {{ 2,'E' }, 0 },
            {{3,'A'},0 }, {{3,'B'},0 }, {{ 3,'C' }, 0}, {{ 3,'D' }, 0 }, {{ 3,'E' }, 0 },
            {{4,'A'},0 }, {{4,'B'},0 }, {{ 4,'C' }, 0}, {{ 4,'D' }, 0 }, {{ 4,'E' }, 0 },
            {{5,'A'},0 }, {{5,'B'},0 }, {{ 5,'C' }, 0}, {{ 5,'D' }, 0 }, {{ 5,'E' }, 0 }};
    };

    class MiniVan : public vehicle {
    private:
        std::string type = "MiniVan";
    public:
        // Seats map. <int, char> represents seats id(1A 1B 1C) the <int> will be either 0 or 1, representing if the seat is taken(1) or free(0).
        std::map<std::pair<int, char>, int> seats{ {{1,'A'},0 }, {{1,'B'},0 }, {{ 1,'C' }, 0},
            {{2,'A'},0 }, {{2,'B'},0 }, {{ 2,'C' }, 0},
            {{3,'A'},0 }, {{3,'B'},0 }, {{ 3,'C' }, 0},
            {{4,'A'},0 }, {{4,'B'},0 }, {{ 4,'C' }, 0} };
    };
    void vehicle::displaySeats()
    {
        std::pair<int, char> seat{ 1, 'E'};
        int columns = 5?this->seats.count(seat)>0:3;
    
        int displayRow = 0;
        for (const auto& p : this->seats) {
            if (displayRow == columns) {
                std::cout << std::endl;
                displayRow = 0;
            }
            displayRow++;
            std::cout << p.first.first << p.first.second << "\t ";
        }
        
    };
```

In main() i have:

```
MiniVan testMiniVan;
testMiniVan.displaySeats();
```

It displays the empty seats map attribute from the base class.
I am new to c++, but in other languages, it takes the derived class attribute. How can I solve this problem? Will I have to  create displaySeats for each child class ? If  yes, then why do I need base class in the first place?

Comment: Yea, I do know about virtual, but this is not what I am looking for! I don't want to create a method displaySeats for every derived class. My goal is to use the base class method with derived class attribute.

Comment: And `virtual` methods are the way to accomplish that task.  But creating a method `displaySeats` for every derived class is NOT the way to accomplish that task.

Comment: Member variables can't be `virtual` like member functions can be. You're shadowing the base class `seats` variable with the `seats`s in the child classes.

Comment: I am currently trying to do exactly that. The answer below gave a good suggestion to use get_seats in the derived classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something I've done fairly often as well, the issue is how things are constructed and which functions have access to which variables. Maybe you could do something like:

```
class Vehicle {
    private:
        int id = 0;
        std::map<std::pair<int, char>, int> seats{};
    public:
        // Add a constructor that takes in the `seats` map
        Vehicle(std::map<std::pair<int, char>, int> s) : seats(std::move(s)) {}
        void displaySeats();
};
```

and then for each child class:

```
class MiniVan : public Vehicle {
    private:
        std::string type = "MiniVan";
    public:
        // call the parent constructor passing in the seat map
        MiniVan() : Vehicle({{1,'A'},0 }, ...}) {}
};
```

Another approach would be to make a virtual function on the base class like:

```
class Vehicle {
    ...
    protected:
        ...
        const std::map<std::pair<int, char>, int>& get_seats() const = 0;
};
```

that the `displaySeats` function would call instead of directly loading `this->seats`. Each child class would need to define `get_seats()`, but that would be pretty easy (pretty much just `return seats;`). Hopefully that makes sense, let me know if not!

Comment: I managed to make it work with your 2nd suggestion. Thank you !!!